# Is there a way to capture all outbound soap requests?

Tags: php, apache, soap, soap-client

I am migrating a bunch of PHP code to a new server. The code is used to make SOAP calls to a remote server for pushing and pulling info (database syncing). I have identified many of the scripts needing to be updated, but cannot be 100% sure that I have everything and the guy who developed this stuff is no longer with the company.

My question is, is there a way to capture and log all SOAP requests from the server? This way I will be able to pinpoint exactly what is running. Perhaps turn on logging for the PHP SoapClient constructor? I wasn't able to find a way to do it. If not, perhaps Apache (LAMP stack [CentOS 6.5]) or another service running on the server can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SoapClient::__getLastRequest() and SoapClient::__getLastResponse(), then log the output using error_log or another logging platform.

You could then use a tool like SoapUI to manually send requests to the server, which would help in debugging requests.

You need to set 'trace' to true in the options array of the constructor for these methods to be enabled.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php

Comment: Thanks, but this would be for each individual request I believe. What I need is a "switch" I can turn on server-wide that logs each request for me to go back and view at a later time. The reason is that I do not know all of the script locations and what/when things are running.

Comment: You can't do this natively with SoapClient. One way to work around it could be to extend SoapClient then override the methods that your application calls and making them log the output of __getLastRequest()/__getLastResponse() in addition to parent::<name of function that you are overriding with arguments>. Some refactoring could make your app then use your custom SoapClient instead of the default one.